# Push every new match from regEx in array

Tags: arrays, regex, google-apps-script

I try to parse some xml file, with this code:

```
   function parseXml() {
      var url = 'http://www.inpo.ru/documents/pricelists/pricelist.xml';
      var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

      var parseregexp = new RegExp (/.*em><no>(\d+)<\/no><title>(.+?)<\/title><price vat="\w+">(\d+.\d+|\d+)<\/price><unit>(.+?)<\/unit><free>(\d+)<\/free>(.|\s)*?<it/g)
      var parsedData = '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 '
      var rangeRegex = [];

      var Pdata = xml.replace(parseregexp,parsedData)

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
      ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(Pdata)
      }
```

And here is xml fragment:

```
<item><no>48514</no><title>The workpiece is the rod d 8x150mm P6AM5 HRC 64-66" CNIC"</title><price vat="yes">154.58</price><unit>Pcs</unit><free>59</free><remarks>Used to make an axial tool.
Hardness HRC64-66</remarks><img thumbnail="http://www.inpo.ru/index/I:48528/THUMBNAIL:0.jpg">http://www.inpo.ru/index/I: 48528 / PREVIEW: 0.jpg</img></item><item><no>48515</no><title>The workpiece is the rod d 8x200mm P6AM5 HRC 64-66"CNIC"</title><price vat="Yes">198.24</price><unit>pcs</unit><free>32</free><remarks>Used to make an axial tool.
Hardness HRC64-66</remarks><img thumbnail="http://www.inpo.ru/index/I:48528/THUMBNAIL:0.jpg">http://www.inpo.ru/index/I: 48528 / PREVIEW: 0.jpg</img></item>
```

And result in Pdata is:

```
48514 The workpiece is the rod d 8x150mm P6AM5 HRC 64-66" CNIC" 154.58 Pcs 59 48515 The workpiece is the rod d 8x200mm P6AM5 HRC 64-66"CNIC" 198.24 pcs 32
```

In this example in Pdata I have 1 long string from all regex matches. How I can make an array with 5 columns from all matches? I think to push every match to array with "for" cycle, but dont know how it's mades. Would be pleasefull for any help

Comment: You should post the value assigned to the variable `Pdata`.  Otherwise we must run your code.  We shouldn't need to do that.  It seems like you may need to split the data into elements in an array.

Comment: @SandyGood Yes, you are right, I added it in question

Comment: Where do you want to split the content?  at **48514** and **48515**?

Comment: I want to store 48514 and 48515 in cells A2 and A3. And next matches from $2 $3 $4 $5 entires in B2 C2 D2 E2 and B3 C3 D3 E3

Comment: Have you tired using this! [Xmlservice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternate Solution:**
Since you are trying to access xml data you can use [XMLservice.parser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

However there seems to a problem in the fetch call, I was unable to get the whole data **(fetch gives a truncated file, perhaps it is timing out, 16mb file)** , so I downloaded the data file and uploaded it into google drive. 
This file could be used to parse XML data like so:

```
function parseXml() {

      var file = DriveApp.getFileById("Xml File ID")   //Get the id of the uploaded file and replace it for "Xml File ID"
      var xml = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
      // The below code gave a error for XML parser
     /*var url = 'http://www.inpo.ru/documents/pricelists/pricelist.xml';
       var options = {
       'method' : 'get',
       'contentType': 'application/xml',
       }
      var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getBlob().getDataAsString()
      Logger.log(xml)*/
     // End of code with gave an error

 var arrayItems = []
 var XmlElem = ["no","title","price","unit","free"]       //Elements to look for
 var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
 var RCounter = 0
 var groups = document.getRootElement().getChildren();   //GetGroup Element
    for(var k = 0; k< groups.length; k++){               // Loop through each group element
      var main = groups[k].getChildren()                // Get sub groups in each group
  for (var j=0 ; j < main.length; j++){                 // Loop through each subGroups

   var mainChilds = main[j].getChildren()               //Get items in each subGroups
   for (var l = 0 ; l < mainChilds.length; l++){        // Loop through each items
   var items = mainChilds[l].getChildren();             // Get  elemetns like "no","title","price","units","free" in each item 
     arrayItems[RCounter] = []
   var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     // Logger.log(items[i].getName())
      var index = XmlElem.indexOf(items[i].getName())       //Look for items and place the value at corresponding index
      if(index != -1)
        arrayItems[RCounter][index] = items[i].getValue()
     }  //End Loope for elements
     if(arrayItems[RCounter].length > 0)                   //in case the array is empty, reuse it
      RCounter++
    }   // End loop for items
    }   // End loop for sub Groups
    }   // End loop for Groups
  Logger.log(arrayItems) 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it works perfect, Thak you Jack! In combination with download funktion, it gaves great tool for refreshing data. But I have only one question, is this code applyeble for other xml files with different structure, if I just change XmlElem var?

Comment: If the structure of the XML file remains the same, yes! The above solution looks for the following structure {group} {group}{item}{XML element}{/item}{/group}{/group}

Comment: Hey again, Jack! Script, that you create, worked perfect till today.. I have an errore: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (at string: "var document = XmlService.parse(xml);") I assume that the file could be loaded with an error, how can I avoid it in the future? If it makes it difficult for you then it's okay if my comment remains unanswered